# audio player to switch between radio streams

Tags: javascript, html

How can i have two radio streams playing through one audio player but at specific time one after the other
like from 4am to 7am one stream plays and then from 7am to 10am i play another audio stream then from 10am to 12am i play another audio stream and so on.......
have limited knowledge in javascript and have been told it is only way i could get it done

```
IQRA_VOICE Scheduler


<h1>IQRA VOICE Scheduler</h1>

    


const audioPlayer = new Audio();
const schedule = [
  { time: '2:30:00 PM', duration: 288, src: 'https://s22.myradiostream.com/16414/listen.mp3' },
  { time: '5:05:00 PM', duration: 30, src: './music/mukwano.mp3' },
  { time: '03:32:00 PM', duration: 60, src: './music/Vyper Rankings - Intro.mp3' },
  { time: '6:00:00 PM', duration: 588, src: 'https://s13.myradiostream.com/40212/listen.mp3' },
  { time: '6:10:00 PM', duration: 288, src: 'http://s22.myradiostream.com/16414' },
];

schedule.forEach(event => {
  const [time, period] = event.time.split(' ');
  const [hour, minute, second] = time.split(':');
  const timestamp = new Date().setHours(hour % 12 + (period === 'PM' ? 12 : 0), minute, second);
  const now = Date.now();

  if (now < timestamp) {
    const delay = timestamp - now;
    audioPlayer.src = event.src;

    setTimeout(() => {
      audioPlayer.Play()
        .then(() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            audioPlayer.pause();
            audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
          }, event.duration * 1000);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Failed to play audio: ' + error);
        });
    }, delay);
  }
});
</script>
```

this is what i tried but only one stream plays and the other doesnot and when I refresh it stops playing